can someone help me with this i am trying to push on my main branch
! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/soham203/Authenticator-DID-.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes,
hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
unable to push terminal is throwing this

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart

The error message is telling you everything you need to know.

Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

The local branch you're trying to push is behind its counterpart on the remote. i.e., the remote's branch has some changes that your local branch doesn't have; therefore, Git is preventing you from overriding those changes.
The message is also telling you how to resolve your issue, where you first need to pull the new changes from the remote and integrate them into your local branch before attempting another push.

hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.

